# Narrow types to avoid writing the same code twice

Tags: typescript

There are 3 Class types:

```
class Options {
  activities: Activity[];
  services: Service[];
}

class Activity {
  activity: string;
  charged: boolean;
  locked: boolean;
}

class Service {
  service: string;
  charged: boolean;
  locked: boolean;
}

type Item = {
  name: string;
  charged: boolean;
  locked: boolean;
};
```

In my code, without handling the types properly, I can write 2 separate functions like below:

```
onActivitiesChanged = (items: Item[]) => {
    const newOptions: Options = this.options || new Options();
    newOptions.activities = items.map(item => ({
      activity: item.name,
      charged: item.charged,
      locked: item.locked,
    }));
  };

onServicesChanged = (items: Item[]) => {
    const newOptions: Options = this.options || new Options();
    newOptions.services = items.map(item => ({
      service: item.name,
      charged: item.charged,
      locked: item.locked,
    }));
  };
```

Looking at this code duplication, I felt there should be a better way to write one function to handle both cases. But I end up with errors because Typescript isn't able to narrow down the types. I have to add 2 different cases in Switch (with the same code repeated):

```
onItemsChanged = ({
    items,
    optionType,
    field,
  }:
    | {
        items: Item[];
        optionType: keyof Pick<Options, 'activities'>;
        field: keyof Pick<Activity, 'activity'>;
      }
    | {
        items: Item[];
        optionType: keyof Pick<Options, 'services'>;
        field: keyof Pick<Service, 'service'>;
      }) => {
    const newOptions: Options = this.options || new Options();
    switch (optionType) {
      case 'activities':
        newOptions[optionType] = items.map(item => ({
          [field]: item.name,
          charged: item.charged,
          locked: item.locked,
        }));
        break;
      case 'services':
        newOptions[optionType] = items.map(item => ({
          [field]: item.name,
          charged: item.charged,
          locked: item.locked,
        }));
        break;
    }
  };
```

Is there a better way to handle this kind of type narrowing without code duplication?

Comment: an [MRE] would sure help. lot harder to work on these if i have to recreate all the types you use in your code

Comment: i dont know if this is a mistake but you also didnt emit for the activities changed. your new code behaves differently from the old code at runtime

Comment: @mocha thanks for checking this. I have removed the emit, as its not relevant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I will also post a minimal example soon..

Comment: [mre] for anyone else interested. frankly there is no "good" solution to this problem/pattern besides good ole' ts-ignore. i know there's a few issues on the github repo but i don't remember any of the numbers... x_x

Comment: I think that normalizing your data structures and adding a field to [discriminate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) them will be helpful here ([example](https://tsplay.dev/m3qoLw))